# Instantiating C# Class Members in C++ using COM

Tags: c#, c++, class, com

I would like to create a C# class object in C++ and set its member fields.
Although I am able to create a C++ class object, I am unable to access it's members and set member field values.

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for AQS Entity
/// </summary>
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("70F12A44-B91D-474D-BD70-32B1ACE041D6")]
[ProgId("AQSEntity")]
public class AQSEntity : IEntity
{

    public AQSEntity()
    {
        sRecoveryDBName = String.Empty;
        arrSourceMailboxesEntity = null;
        sQueryString = String.Empty;
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string sRecoveryDBName = string.Empty;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public MailBoxCollection arrSourceMailboxesEntity;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string sQueryString;


}
```

and the IEntity class is defined below

```
[Guid("5C71057E-9FD9-47D5-B022-8D5F9C7007D3")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IEntity
{
}
```

In C++,

```
IEntity* pTest1 = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(**AQSEntity**),NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(IEntity),(void**)&pTest1);
```

I want to access members of AQSEntity class in C++. But I am unable to access them.

pTest1-> sQueryString

gives error.

> 'sQueryString' : is not a member of
>   'AsigraExchange::IEntity' C:\PROJECTS\COM\COMClient\COMClient.cpp 168

Can anyone please suggest where I am wrong.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Your interface is completely empty.  Add properties and methods to it.  Don't add fields.

Comment: There are other classes implementing IEntity. If I add properties and methods to IEntity, those classes cannot inherit from IEntity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything behaves exactly as it should :)

In your C++ project, you are allowed to access all the methods declared on your `IEntity` interface, which there are none.

Your implementation, i.e. `AQSEntity` class, should implement all the `IEntity` members. The methods which are now declared in that class are member of the class, they are not related to `IEntity` in any way.

This means you need to declare all the required methods inside `IEntity` interface and then implement them in `AQSEntity`. Notice that you are also exposing the fields of the class, not the methods. You will have to define methods (or properties, which will get converted to methods on C++ side) and then implement them. Something like:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public string RecoveryDBName { get; }
}
```

You also have to specify `[MarshalAs]` attributes in the interface, although `UnmanagedType.BStr` is default for strings, so you can omit them.

EDIT:

based on comments, it seems that `IEntity` is just a marker interface, not intended to be exposed as an API (attributes might be better option here, as `IEntity` won't be used on client side anyway).

In this case there are two options:

1) better approach, although it requires more work: derive `IAQSEntity` interface from `IEntity`, declare methods on it, and implement that on `AQSEntity` class

2) less work, but more brittle: Mark `AQSEntity` as `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` instead of `ClassInterfaceType.None` - this will expose the members to COM clients, but will be much harder to version and it will also expose the base type members.

Here's what I would choose:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
...
[Entity]  // instead of IEntity marker interface
public class AQSEntity : IAQSEntity
{
    public string RecoveryDbName { get; }
}

[Guid("...")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IAQSEntity // no base interface IEntity!
{
    string RecoveryDbName { get; }        
}
```

The only drawback of using `Entity` attribute instead of `IEntity` marker interface is if you want to use the interface as constraint for generics

Comment: There are other classes implementing IEntity. If I add properties and methods to IEntity, those classes cannot inherit from IEntity.

Comment: Then you need `IAQS` interface derived from entity. COM aside, how would you access `AQSEntity` members via `IEntity` in C#? no way - it seems to be a marker interface in your case. Another option is using `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` instead of `ClassInterfaceType.None`, but it is considered a bad practice.

Comment: I am changing my design as per the suggestions in this post. Thanks

Comment: make sure to read the docs on `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` and especially the caveats if you go down that path - it has drawbacks with regard to versioning and exposing the base type methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface does indeed not contain any members. You need to put the members into the interface and then implement that interface in your class.

Comment: There are other classes implementing IEntity. If I add properties and methods to IEntity, those classes cannot inherit from IEntity. I annot add fields to an Interface

Comment: Well, that's your problem, not a technical one. Why do you implement your COM interface for other classes than the one you want to expose to COM? Don't do it. The fact that you cannot add fields should tell you something about your class design. Don't use public fields.